# Updating entity tree with deep nested entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My app deals with saving orders received from an external system. The order contains child items like line items, address, fulfillments, refunds > refund items etc.

Currently, I use an ugly looking code to detect what has changed in each entity by its External Id. Can someone recommend me a better way? :)

Following is a simplified entity model of `Order`

```cs
public class Order 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalOrderId { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    public List<Fulfillment> Fulfillments { get; set; }
    public ShippingAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Refund> Refunds { get; set; }
    public string FinancialStatus { get; set; }
    public string FulfillmentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalLineItemId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class Fulfillment 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalFulfillmentId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string TrackingUrl { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class ShippingAddress 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalShippingAddressrId { get; set; }
    public string Addres { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class Refund 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalRefundId { get; set; }
    public List<RefundedItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    public string CancelledReason { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class RefundedItem 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalRefundedItemId { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My sample code:

```cs
private async Task ManageFulfillments(long orderId, Order order)
{
    if (order.Fulfillments == null || !order.Fulfillments.Any()) return;

    var newFulfillmentIds = order.Fulfillments.Select(c => c.ExternalFulfillmentId).ToList();
    var dbFulfillments = await _fulfillmentRepository.GetAll().IgnoreQueryFilters()
        .Where(c => c.OrderId == orderId)
        .Select(c => new { c.Id, c.ExternalFulfillmentId }).ToListAsync();
    var dbFulfillmentIds = dbFulfillments.Select(c => c.ExternalFulfillmentId).ToList();

    // Delete Fulfillments that are not present in new Fulfillments list
    var deletedFulfillments = dbFulfillmentIds.Except(newFulfillmentIds).ToList();
    if (deletedFulfillments.Any())
    {
        await _fulfillmentRepository.DeleteAsync(c =>
        deletedFulfillments.Contains(c.ExternalFulfillmentId) && c.ExternalOrderId == orderId);
    }

    // Update existing Fulfillments ids
    order.Fulfillments
        .Where(c => dbFulfillmentIds.Contains(c.ExternalFulfillmentId))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(async c =>
        {
            c.Id = dbFulfillments.Where(p => p.ExternalFulfillmentId == c.ExternalFulfillmentId)
                .Select(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            await _fulfillmentRepository.UpdateAsync(c);
        });

    // New Fulfillments will automatically be added by EF
}
```

I have similar code in place to update other entites as well and I'm not proud of it!

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Performance or nice code formatting? Are there FK's pointing to LineItem, Fulfillment, ShippingAddress, RefundedItem? If there aren't you could just re-create your order each time. It's not good for permormance but it would look nice in code. You could also achieve both with adding a stored procedure and just invoking it within the ManageFulfillments function.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what happening at your code but I can suggest to split your ManageFulfillments method to some more methods. Practically each code part that you commented can be a method. And when I look that method I think that method can be an independent Class with that contains add, update, delete methods. And looks like you can use builder pattern to create this class.

Comment: @Gleb I'm more concerned about performance here.
I have to fetch existing fulfilment ids and compare it with new ones and also check what is deleted, updated and so on.

I could just recreate the child entities again, but the problem would be, there are 1000s of orders everyday and 5000+ changes which means the order will have to be recreated everytime and changing the primary key could be troublesome

Comment: @nzrytmn I am checking which child entites are changed, deleted or added. And I have to check this for fulfillment, line items, refunds etc which is not so performant. Do you have a better idea here? :)

Comment: @AjayKumar are you concerning about Performance or solid principles of code ? If you update , delete a bulk of entities than better to use Bulk operations of Entityframework https://entityframework.net/bulk-update

Comment: @nzrytmn, In this case, I'm concerned about performance.
I don't think bulk updating would be a solution here. I'm not updating many orders.
Consider this example:
You place an order. You have information such as order items, address, etc. and now I want to create or update this information.

Comment: In case, the order is new, it is as simple as 1 line of code. EF will automatically create the links between child entity and save it.
In case, the order is existing, I need to check what has changed in the order manually. I need to check if item is added in order, or an item is deleted from the order.
Do you understand my problem here? :)